# Truncated incorrect time value after converting from seconds to time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the sum of each user's drive time through various time functions and conversions in MySQL. However, for some reason, my code is no longer working, even though it was working earlier today and I did not make any changes.

This is what I am trying to run

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS super_users;

 /* creates empty table */ 
CREATE TABLE super_users(
super_user_name VARCHAR (50), 
total_drives INT (3),
total_paid DECIMAL (10, 2),
total_drive_time VARCHAR(40),
average_paid DECIMAL (10, 2),
average_drive_time VARCHAR(40),
total_months_of_driving INT (2),
id VARCHAR (40));

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

/* imports all user ids into table */    
INSERT INTO super_users(id)
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM drive_data_final
GROUP BY id; 

    UPDATE super_users
    SET total_drive_time = (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(drive_end_time, drive_start_time)))) FROM drive_data_final WHERE id = super_users.id);
```

However, I keep getting

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value: '3300971'

I've tried breaking down the code into smaller portions and had no issues when I took out the `SEC_TO_TIME` part and doing `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(total_drive_time)`afterwards gives me the values that I want to save. However, when I tried

```
UPDATE super_users
    SET total_drive_time = (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(drive_end_time, drive_start_time))) FROM drive_data_final WHERE id = super_users.id);

UPDATE super_users
    SET total_drive_time = SEC_TO_TIME(total_drive_time);
```

returns the same error as well. I have no idea why this error is even occurring when it was working completely fine earlier.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: edit to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE super_users`. What MySQL version (`SELECT VERSION()`)?

Comment: The version is 8.0.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SEC_TO_TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) returns a `TIME`, therefore total_drive_time should be a `TIME` rather than a `VARCHAR`

The seconds in a day is 86400 and your sum 3300971 is bigger than that. `SEC_TO_TIME` only converts to hours, minutes and seconds, not days.

Comment: you've exceeded a day (even a month) in your sum total.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still, at some point this query worked in the sense that I got 3 digit hours (ex: 103:12:10), which was good and I thought it was possible to get HHH:MM:SS along with HH:MM:SS. Is there a way to change the limit or do I have to manually divide out seconds in a day before changing the result using SEC_TO_TIME?